# Как делать CORS запросы?

Tags: ajax, json, api, cors

**Доброго времени суток.**

Подскажите пожалуйста по поводу CORS запросов, пытаюсь дернуть JSON с своего сервера, какие заголовки должен отдавать сервер при JSON запросе, а какие должен отдавать клиент.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение нашел.

Раньше не выходило, после повторной попытки (через 5 дней), все заработало.

**Заголовки сервера:** 

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*"  
Content-Type:"application/json"  
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:"GET"

**Заголовки клиента:** 

Accept:"application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"