# GET запрос и ошибка CORS

Tags: javascript, get, cors

Сделал GET запрос с помощью JS https://pastebin.com/kcCdiRxe ,добавил CORS в заголовки,но все равно выводить ошибки в консоле. В чем может быть проблема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в `DevTools`, какие хедеры приходят от сервера?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko [https://i.imgur.com/bKycLTN.png](Вот)

Comment: Это не хедеры, это ошибки в консоли)) Вы перейдите во вкладку `Networks`, там нажмите на ошибочный CORS запрос и посмотрите вкладку `Headers`. Там должен присутствовать установленный вами заголовок.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы разрешаете CORS на одном ресурсе, но он не обрабатывает запрос сам, а делает редирект на другой ресурс.

В этом случае все промежуточные ресурсы как и конечный должны иметь заголовки разрешающие CORS с вашего домена.

**Ведь как реализованы редиректы?**
Сервер возвращает ответ на первый запрос с кодом 3хх и клиент должен сделать совершенно новый, практически независимый запрос на ресурс, указанный в заголовке `Location` ответа.
Браузер делает это вполне прозрачно, однако каждый такой запрос независимо  подвергается проверкам политик безопасности, в т.ч. CORS.

---

Варианты решения:

1. Разрешить CORS на всех участниках общения
2. Прокси - не делать редирект, вместо это получить необходимую информацию непосредственно с первого сервера, которую и отдать клиенту.
3. Сторонняя прокси - существуют специальные сервисы для обхода этой пробемы, по факту реализованный другими участниками вариант 2. Например: [cors.io](https://cors.io)

Comment: Да, на срине не до конца понятно, но видимо редирект, тут проще всего сделать в php - `echo file_get_contens(урл_куда_редиректит)` и удалить хедер

Comment: Может проще, а может и нет... Кто знает наверняка?

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко, принцип работы с сервером таков вы отсылаете запрос с заголовками, 
сервер отвечает вам заголовками, посмотреть их вы сможете, в консоле разработчика.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше с вопросом сталкивался вот ответ: 
[Как делать CORS запросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756531/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-cors-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B)

Answer (score 0):

[Есть такая штука](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/)

```
This API enables cross-origin requests to anywhere.

Usage:

/               Shows help
/iscorsneeded   This is the only resource on this host which is served without CORS headers.
/<url>          Create a request to <url>, and includes CORS headers in the response.

If the protocol is omitted, it defaults to http (https if port 443 is specified).

Cookies are disabled and stripped from requests.

Redirects are automatically followed. For debugging purposes, each followed redirect results
in the addition of a X-CORS-Redirect-n header, where n starts at 1. These headers are not
accessible by the XMLHttpRequest API.
After 5 redirects, redirects are not followed any more. The redirect response is sent back
to the browser, which can choose to follow the redirect (handled automatically by the browser).

The requested URL is available in the X-Request-URL response header.
The final URL, after following all redirects, is available in the X-Final-URL response header.


To prevent the use of the proxy for casual browsing, the API requires either the Origin
or the X-Requested-With header to be set. To avoid unnecessary preflight (OPTIONS) requests,
it's recommended to not manually set these headers in your code.


Demo          :   https://robwu.nl/cors-anywhere.html
Source code   :   https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/
Documentation :   https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/#documentation
```

Добавляешь перед своим url и запросы осуществляются с cors( по ссылке подробнее)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Стоп.. А это точно ответ?