# блокировка CORS на стороне back end

Tags: node.js, express, cors

Есть back end написанная на nodejs,expressjs. А так же есть front end написанная на react js. При отправке запроса с front end на back end возникает ошибка CORS. Некоторые советуют отключить web security на chrome, отключил, работает. Но на других браузерах не работает. Как можно обойти CORS ?

Back end и front end имеют разные порты

Comment: Почитать, что такое CORS, узнать про Access-Control-Allow-Origin и соответствующим образом настроить back end?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как делать CORS запросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756531/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-cors-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

Для `express` есть специальный пакет для настройки `CORS` https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Установка выглядит примерно так:
`npm i cors`

```
// тут импорт Express и прочих пакетов
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://example.com', // домен сервиса, с которого будут приниматься запросы
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // для старых браузеров
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions)); // если не указать corsOptions, то запросы смогут слать все запросы

// Так же можно добавить CORS не всем роутам, а одному определенному 
app.get('/cors', cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  res.json({msg: 'success!'});
})
```

[В репозитории пакета](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) больше примеров, например для нескольких доменов

[Подробнее про CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)